# Top rounded gradient drawable

Tags: android

i need to create a GradientDrawable object with only the top rounded corners.

Actually i'm using this method:

```
public static GradientDrawable generateGradientBackground(String topColor, String bottomColor) {
    int[] colors = {Color.parseColor(topColor), Color.parseColor(bottomColor)};

    //create a new gradient color
    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.BL_TR, colors);
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setCornerRadius(30f);

    return gd;
}
```

This way, all corners are rounded. I can't find a way to set the radius of only top corners. Ay ideas?

I know similar question have been asked, but no solutions seems good in my case.

Thanks

Comment: where you want to do  top rounded corners in LinearLayout  or ImageView ...?????

Comment: i have a frame layout where i want to apply programmatically a gradient. Since it's the top of a card, i want the gradient to be rounded only on top-right and top-left. In xml it's very easy, with java i can't figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `setCornerRadii (float[] radii)`

You can supply radii for each of the 4 corners. For each corner, the array contains 2 values, [X_radius, Y_radius]. The corners are ordered top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left.

```
gd.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 8, 8, 8, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0 });
```

Comment: I can't do this. I need for my code to dinamically change color using java. I don't want to create a different drawable for every gradient

Comment: @MarioRossi: Updated the answer. please check